# Group rows by two columns and filter values by comparison

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to:

- create a new dataframe (df2)
- this new dataframe will contain rows from df1
- to add these rows to df2 I have been grouped the columns in df1 by month and element
- I would only select the values that exceed their monthly peers in df (for example if month 1 in df1 has 10 values that exceed the month 1 value in df I would include those 10 values in the new dataframe)

What I am failing to do now is to compare the values of each row grouped by month, against the monthly equivalent in df (which contains the maximum values per month)

- I would like to select only the rows from df1 that have values that exceed their monthly peers in df

I got a solution from a stackoverflow user that allows me to get the maximum values for each month. Problem is in some cases there are more than 2 values in df1 that exceed the month equivalent in df.

This is the code I have so far:

```
df4 = df3[df3['Element'] =='TMAX'].groupby("Month").max()
df3_max = df4[df4.Data_Value > df_max.Data_Value]
df5 = df3[df3['Element'] =='TMIN'].groupby("Month").min()
df4_min = df5[(df5.Data_Value) < (df_min.Data_Value)]
```

This is df:

```
        Data_Value
   Month    
    1.0   217.0
    2.0   194.0
    3.0   317.0
    4.0   306.0
    5.0   367.0
    6.0   406.0
    7.0   406.0
    8.0   372.0
    9.0   372.0
    10.0    328.0
    11.0    256.0
    12.0    194.0
```

df1 (sample- full data has >1000 rows):

```
    ID             Date   Element  Data_Value  Month
0   USW00094889 2014-11-12  TMAX    220.0   11.0
1   USC00208972 2009-04-29  TMAX    560.0   1.0
2   USC00200032 2008-05-26  TMAX    278.0   5.0
3   USC00205563 2005-11-11  TMAX    239.0   11.0
4   USC00200230 2014-02-27  TMAX    -106.0  2.0
5   USW00014833 2010-10-01  TMAX    194.0   10.0
6   USC00207308 2010-06-29  TMIN    144.0   6.0
7   USC00203712 2005-10-04  TMAX    289.0   10.0
8   USW00004848 2007-12-14  TMIN    -16.0   12.0
9   USC00200220 2011-04-21  TMAX    72.0    4.0
10  USC00205822 2013-01-16  TMAX    411.0   1.0
11  USC00205822 2008-05-29  TMIN    28.0    5.0
12  USC00203712 2008-10-17  TMIN    17.0    10.0
13  USC00205563 2006-05-14  TMAX    183.0   5.0
```

This is my expected output (df2):

```
        Data_Value
   Month    
    1.0   560.0
    1.0   411.0
```

So from the df1 dataframe, only the 2nd and 11th row would be added to df2 because the values of these rows exceed the values from month 1 in df

Comment: Can you add expected output, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Please also add df2 and your sample output. Your typed text is too confusing to read and can be easily misinterpreted. Maybe try bulletpointing it.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, I have updated he question to help make it clearer

Comment: @ycx I have edited the question and broke it into hopefully more digestible points... and added the desired outcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for `Series` with same size like `df2`, so possible compare, only necessary unique values of months in `df.index`:

```
df3 = df1[df1['Data_Value'] > df1['Month'].map(df['Data_Value'])]
print (df3)
            vID        Date Element  Data_Value  Month
1   USC00208972  2009-04-29    TMAX       560.0    1.0
10  USC00205822  2013-01-16    TMAX       411.0    1.0
```